# ViewPager return type mismatch error when using android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity

I used [this example of ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) in my app and to solve the

> "android.support.v13.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter error: cannot be
>   resolved error"

used in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23492361/3990512). But I got a new

> "return type-mismatch error"

because the `create()` method returns `com.example.ScreenSlidePageFragment`:

```
public class ScreenSlidePageFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_PAGE = "page";
    private int mPageNumber;
    public static ScreenSlidePageFragment create(int pageNumber) {
        ScreenSlidePageFragment fragment = new ScreenSlidePageFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, pageNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
```

which is not compatible with what should be returned in `getItem()` method:

```
private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return ScreenSlidePageFragment.create(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }
}
```

> **Error**
>
> Error:(443, 41) error: incompatible types required: Fragment found:
>   ScreenSlidePageFragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> android.support.**v13**.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter error: cannot be
>   resolved error

**You should import this one:**

```
 import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
```

Not `import android.support.v13.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;`

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to import `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` in `ScreenSlidePageFragment` instead of `android.app.Fragment`.